# How does the Clojure repl know where to find classes which are not explicitly declared on the classpath?

Tags: clojure

In the Clojure repl I type:

```
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showMessageDialog nil "Hello World")
```

and a nice Swing dialogue box appears. When I started the repl I did not tell it where to find the Swing library. How does it know? How can I found where on my system it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question:

The Java Runtime has the Swing classes loaded at the start of the JVM. They are found (on Ubuntu) in the rt.jar Jar file found here:

/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib

Comment: The more general answer is that swing is part of java, and will come with most versions of java and be available by default.